# OpenXML SDK 2.5 Excel Template

Tags: c#

Hi all (sorry please for my bad english). I need make excel file (`xlsx`) with my data from template. 
I have a template

[image: template screen shot]

And data for test

```
    public class MyC
    {
        public String AAA { get; private set; }
        public String BBB { get; private set; }
        public String CCC { get; private set; }

        public MyC(String a, String b, String c)
        {
            AAA = a;
            BBB = b;
            CCC = c;
        }
    }

            var my = new List<MyC>
            {
                new MyC("a1", "b1", "c1"),
                new MyC("a2", "b2", "c2"),
                new MyC("a3", "b3", "c3"),
            };
```

And I need find label in template with name DataField: and replace on my data.
And get something like this

[image]

And need save styles like in template.

P.S. I try do it self, but i can't. Help me please.

Answer (score 6):

I did it myself.
And I want publish the code, for people who are interested this theme.
I will be write my data in excel with template.
Fist you need download Open XML SDK dll (i use version 2.5)
and add in project (i add in Worker)

I have in Disc C, my template (C:\ExcelTemplates\MyTestTemp.xlsx)

[image]

And I wont get next result

[image]

I construct 5 projects.

[image]

1. TestConsole (just console for start project)
2. Interface (for my data)
3. OfficeFramework (here will be general work)
4. TemplateTables (for generate System.Data.DataTable-s)
5. Test (for my test data)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TemplateTables.ExcelTemplates;
using Test;
using OpenFileDialog = System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////// Write my data in Excel File
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog;

            var myData = new List<TestData>//My data for test
            {
                new TestData("a1", "b1", "c1"),
                new TestData("a2", "b2", "c2"),
                new TestData("a3", "b3", "c3"),
                new TestData("a4", "b4", "c4"),
                new TestData("a5", "b5", "c5"),
                new TestData("a6", "b6", "c6")
            };
            try
            {
                var wk = new OfficeFramework.Create.Worker();//general class for work
                var ex = new TestTable();
                wk.Export(ex.ExcelTableLines(myData), ex.ExcelTableHeader(), "MyTestTemp");//here i generate DataTeble, labels and send in public void Export(DataTable dataTable, System.Collections.Hashtable hashtable, String templateName) and send my template file name "MyTestTemp"
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

using System;

namespace Interfaces 
{
    public interface ITestData // interface for my data
    {
        String AAA { get; }
        String BBB { get; }
        String CCC { get; }
    }
}

using System;
using Interfaces;

namespace Test
{
    public class TestData : ITestData // my data class
    {
        public String AAA { get; private set; }
        public String BBB { get; private set; }
        public String CCC { get; private set; }

        public TestData(String a, String b, String c)
        {
            AAA = a;
            BBB = b;
            CCC = c;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace OfficeFramework.Create
{
    public class CellForFooter // here i will be keep cells for my labels. self cell and value
    {
        public Cell _Cell { get; private set; }
        public String Value { get; private set; }

        public CellForFooter(Cell cell, String value)
        {
            _Cell = cell;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace OfficeFramework.Create
{
    public class Footer //it's rows with cells for labels
    {
        public Row _Row { get; private set; }
        public List<CellForFooter> Cells { get; private set; }

        public Footer(Row row, Cell cell, String cellValue)
        {
            _Row = new Row((Row) row.Clone()) {RowIndex = row.RowIndex};
            var _Cell = (Cell)cell.Clone();
            _Cell.CellReference = cell.CellReference;
            Cells = new List<CellForFooter> { new CellForFooter(_Cell,cellValue) };
        }

        public void AddMoreCell(Cell cell, String cellValue)
        {
            var _Cell = (Cell)cell.Clone();
            _Cell.CellReference = cell.CellReference;
            Cells.Add(new CellForFooter(_Cell, cellValue));
        }
    }
}

using System;

namespace OfficeFramework.Create
{
    public class Field // here i will keep my colums names, rows indexes and column index
    {
        public uint Row { get; private set; }
        public String Column { get; private set; }
        public String _Field { get; private set; }

        public Field(uint row, String column, String field)
        {
            Row = row;
            Column = column;
            _Field = field;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace OfficeFramework.Create
{
    public class Worker
    {
        private const String TemplateFolder = @"C:\ExcelTemplates\";

        public static String Directory
        {
            get
            {
                const string excelFilesPath = @"C:\xls_repository\"; // folder for result files
                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(excelFilesPath) == false)
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(excelFilesPath);
                }

                return excelFilesPath;
            }
        }

        public void Export(DataTable dataTable, System.Collections.Hashtable hashtable, String templateName)
        {
            var filePath = CreateFile(templateName);

            OpenForRewriteFile(filePath, dataTable, hashtable);

            OpenFile(filePath);
        }

        private String CreateFile(String templateName)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(TemplateFolder + templateName + ".xlsx"))
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Не удалось найти шаблон документа \"{0}\"!", TemplateFolder + templateName + ".xlsx"));
            }

            var filePath = Directory + templateName + "_" + Regex.Replace((DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), @"[^a-z0-9]+", "") + ".xlsx";

            File.Copy(TemplateFolder + templateName + ".xlsx", filePath, true);

            return filePath;
        }

        private void OpenForRewriteFile(String filePath, DataTable dataTable, System.Collections.Hashtable hashtable)
        {
            Row rowTemplate = null;
            var footer = new List<Footer>();
            var firsIndexFlag = false; 
            using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
            {
                Sheet sheet;
                try
                {
                    sheet = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Лист1");// get my sheet
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Возможно в документе существует два листа с названием \"Лист1\"!\n",ex);
                }

                if (sheet==null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("В шаблоне не найден Лист1!\n");
                }

                var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id.Value);
                var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

                var rowsForRemove = new List<Row>();
                var fields = new List<Field>();
                foreach (var row in worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>())
                {
                    var celsForRemove = new List<Cell>();
                    foreach (var cell in row.Descendants<Cell>())
                    {
                        if (cell == null)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        var value = GetCellValue(cell, document.WorkbookPart);
                        if (value.IndexOf("DataField:", StringComparison.Ordinal) != -1)
                        {
                            if (!firsIndexFlag)
                            {
                                firsIndexFlag = true;
                                rowTemplate = row;
                            }
                            fields.Add(new Field(Convert.ToUInt32(Regex.Replace(cell.CellReference.Value, @"[^\d]+", ""))
                                , new string(cell.CellReference.Value.ToCharArray().Where(p => !char.IsDigit(p)).ToArray())
                                , value.Replace("DataField:", "")));

                        }

                        if (value.IndexOf("Label:", StringComparison.Ordinal) != -1 && rowTemplate == null)
                        {
                            if (!hashtable.ContainsKey(value.Replace("Label:", "").Trim()))
                            {
                                throw new Exception("Нет такого лэйбла");
                            }
                            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(hashtable[value.Replace("Label:", "").Trim()].ToString());
                            cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

                        }

                        if (rowTemplate == null || row.RowIndex <= rowTemplate.RowIndex || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        var item = footer.SingleOrDefault(p => p._Row.RowIndex == row.RowIndex);
                        if (item == null)
                        {
                            footer.Add(new Footer(row, cell, value.IndexOf("Label:", StringComparison.Ordinal) != -1? hashtable[value.Replace("Label:", "").Trim()].ToString():value));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            item.AddMoreCell(cell, value.IndexOf("Label:", StringComparison.Ordinal) != -1? hashtable[value.Replace("Label:", "").Trim()].ToString():value);
                        }
                        celsForRemove.Add(cell);
                    }

                    foreach (var cell in celsForRemove)
                    {
                        cell.Remove();
                    }

                    if (rowTemplate != null && row.RowIndex != rowTemplate.RowIndex)
                    {
                        rowsForRemove.Add(row);
                    }
                }

                if (rowTemplate == null || rowTemplate.RowIndex == null || rowTemplate.RowIndex<0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Не удалось найти ни одного поля, для заполнения!");
                }

                foreach (var row in rowsForRemove)
                {
                    row.Remove();
                }

                var index = rowTemplate.RowIndex;
                foreach (var row in from DataRow item in dataTable.Rows select CreateRow(rowTemplate, index, item, fields))
                {
                    sheetData.InsertBefore(row, rowTemplate);
                    index++;
                }

                foreach (var newRow in footer.Select(item => CreateLabel(item, (UInt32)dataTable.Rows.Count)))
                {
                    sheetData.InsertBefore(newRow, rowTemplate);
                }

                rowTemplate.Remove();
            }
        }

        private Row CreateLabel(Footer item, uint count)
        {
            var row = item._Row;
            row.RowIndex = new UInt32Value(item._Row.RowIndex + (count - 1));
            foreach (var cell in item.Cells)
            {
                cell._Cell.CellReference = new StringValue(cell._Cell.CellReference.Value.Replace(Regex.Replace(cell._Cell.CellReference.Value, @"[^\d]+", ""), row.RowIndex.ToString()));
                cell._Cell.CellValue = new CellValue(cell.Value);
                cell._Cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                row.Append(cell._Cell);
            }
            return row;
        }

        private Row CreateRow(Row rowTemplate, uint index, DataRow item, List<Field> fields)
        {
            var newRow = (Row)rowTemplate.Clone();
            newRow.RowIndex = new UInt32Value(index);

            foreach (var cell in newRow.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                cell.CellReference = new StringValue(cell.CellReference.Value.Replace(Regex.Replace(cell.CellReference.Value, @"[^\d]+", ""), index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
                foreach (var fil in fields.Where(fil => cell.CellReference == fil.Column + index))
                {
                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(item[fil._Field].ToString());
                    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                }
            }
            return newRow;
        }


        private string GetCellValue(Cell cell, WorkbookPart wbPart)
        {
            var value = cell.InnerText;

            if (cell.DataType == null)
            {
                return value;
            }
            switch (cell.DataType.Value)
            {
                case CellValues.SharedString:

                    var stringTable = wbPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();

                    if (stringTable != null)
                    {
                        value = stringTable.SharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return value;
        }

        private void OpenFile(string filePath)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Не удалось найти файл \"{0}\"!", filePath));
            }

            Process.Start(filePath).WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```