# How can we write data to excel Template and maintain the template format in OpenXML?

Tags: openxml

I am able to read the excel template using openxml, and able to append data to the sheets.
But unable to maintain the existing Excel Template format, and unable to identify the column headings

Please find the below code used

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0] != null || ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count > 0)
                {
                    System.Data.DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];

                    using (var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, true))
                    {
                        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;

                        Sheet sheet = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.GetFirstChild<Sheet>();
                        Worksheet worksheet = (spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id.Value) as WorksheetPart).Worksheet;

                        SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
                        List<String> columns = new List<string>();
                        IEnumerable<Row> rows = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Descendants<Row>();

                        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                        {
                            columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
                            Cell cell = new Cell();
                            cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                        }
                        

                        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                        {
                            Row newRow = new Row();
                            columns.ForEach(col =>
                            {
                                Cell cell = new Cell();
                                //If value is DBNull, do not set value to cell  
                                if (row[col] != System.DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                    cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(row[col].ToString());
                                }
                                newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                            });
                            sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                        }
                        spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                        spreadsheetDocument.Close();
                    }
```

[Please find actual excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a65Yz.jpg)

[please find expected excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQVJs.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your specific problem and provided the actual code snippet and the example template that you are using so we can better understand your issue and assist you on the issue.

There is earlier post “[OpenXML SDK 2.5 Excel Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658267/openxml-sdk-2-5-excel-template)" Find a label in template with name DataField, and replace with data. This might be what you are looking for.